# Does it make sense to "store" all needed requires into one file?

Tags: architecture, reactjs, react-native, amd

I was wondering if it makes sense, to store all your needed require()/imports into one or two js files which you than require in the Components you need any. 
I just figured out, since the Project gets bigger and bigger, i would like to have more space on top of the Class.
I read something about mixins, maybe this is the better solution to 
sum up your require()...Not sure if this would mess up my overview or makes it better...

Maybe someone has a hint?

Answer (score 0):

> I just figured out, since the Project gets bigger and bigger, i would
>   like to have more space on top of the Class.

If you end up with too many imports in your component, maybe you would want to split it rather?

> I was wondering if it makes sense, to store all your needed
>   require()/imports into one or two js files which you than require in
>   the Components you need any.

If you plan to reuse your components through different projects, that would be a bad idea to tie your components dependencies in such a way.